# Using virtualenv on Mac OS X

Tags: django, virtualenv

I'm trying to setup a Django environment on Mac OS X, but I'm getting an error when I try to create a virtual env. Does anyone have a tip for me?

**UPDATE:** I'm sorry for leaving out the error message. It boils down to:

```
Could not call install_name_tool -- you must have Apple's development tools installed
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: With your updated post, then mitchf's answer below is correct. Note if you still have the DVD that came with your Mac, you can insert the DVD and install XCode from there rather than paying $4.99 for it from the app store.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error message would be helpful, but when I recently setup a Django development environment on my Macbook Air, I found that I needed to download an install Xcode to get all the development tools I needed.

You can find Xcode in the Mac Store. It cost $4.99 when I downloaded it a few weeks ago. It is a *huge* download and took all night to get, but once I installed it I was able to use virtualenv.

You can check out my post on [Getting Started with Virtualenv](http://mitchfournier.com/2010/06/25/getting-started-with-virtualenv-isolated-python-environments/) if you need help with that excellent package. Best of luck.

Comment: Your Mac OSX DVD came with a copy of XCode, so I wouldn't recommend paying for it unless you lost the DVD.

Comment: Ahhhh, that tip would have saved $5 and a long night of downloading! The Macbook Air doesn't come with an OSX DVD since it doesn't have a DVD player, but I didn't think to look on the USB flash drive ("MacBook Air Software Reinstall Drive") the that came with it.

Comment: after xcode 4, the Air 'stick' doesn't seem to come with it any longer.